# Teradata String Manipulation (Second Space)

Tags: sql, string, teradata

I'm having great difficulty solving this seemingly easy task:

Purpose:
Create a query that eliminates the middle Initial

Example

```
Name
Smith, John A
Jane, Mary S
```

I would like an output such as this:

```
Name
Smith, John
Jane, Mary
```

Any tips on how to do this with Teradata SQL

I believe I solved the issue, albeit in a very poor way:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('SMITH, JOHN A', 0, (POSITION(' ' IN 'SMITH, JOHN A') + (POSITION(' ' IN SUBSTR('SMITH, JOHN A',(POSITION(' ' IN 'SMITH, JOHN A'))+ 1,50)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a,
substr(a,1,index(a,' '))|| substr(trim(substr(a,index(a,' '))),1,index(trim(substr(a,index(a,' '))),' ')),
substr(trim(substr(a,index(a,' '))),index(trim(substr(a,index(a,' '))),' ')) last_name
from a
```

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is making sure your names are consistently formatted. (`Last_Name, Given_Name Middle_Initial`) If they are then you may be able to solve this with recursive SQL. The following SQL would take `Given_Name Last_Name` and return `Last_Name`. You may be able to tweak it to accomplish your specific task. (My sample data was not consistently formatted so I was stuck trying to find the second (or third) occurrence of a white space character.)

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (FullName, DelimPosition, RecursionLevel, Element, Remainder) AS
(
  SELECT FullName
       , 0 AS DelimPosition_
       , 0 
       , CAST('' AS VARCHAR(128))
       , FullName
    FROM MyDatabase.Persons

  UNION ALL

  SELECT FullName
       , CASE WHEN POSITION(' ' IN Remainder) > 0
              THEN POSITION(' ' IN Remainder)
              ELSE CHARACTER_LENGTH(Remainder)
         END DelimPosition_
       , RecursionLevel + 1
       , SUBSTRING(Remainder FROM 0 FOR DelimPosition_ + 1)
       , SUBSTRING(Remainder FROM DelimPosition_ + 1)
    FROM cte
   WHERE DelimPosition_ > 1
     AND RecursionLevel < 3 -- Set max depth
)
SELECT FullName
     , CASE WHEN POSITION('&' IN Element) = 0
            THEN Element 
            ELSE NULL
       END AS LastName
  FROM cte c
 WHERE RecursionLevel > 2
 ORDER BY FullName;
```

Another option would be to implement a UDF that returns the rightmost *n* characters of a string. (e.g.`RIGHT(FullName, n)`)

If the formatting is not consistent then we have to look at other less graceful options.

Hope this helps.